# how to change date format from dd-MMM-yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: c#, date

I can't change date format, I've tried 2 methods but the output is `0001-01-01`

**Method 1**

```
hf_test.Value = "1-Jul-2013";

DateTime date;
var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(hf_test.Value,
    "dd-MMM-yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out date);

    Resopnse.Write(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

**Method 2**

```
        hf_test.Value = "1-Jul-2013";
        Alert.Show(DateTime.ParseExact(hf_test.Value , "dd-MMM-yyyy", culture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `success`?

Comment: With that date "output", the value of `success` will be `false`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Output of `0001-01-01` means that your date coud not be parsed. The reason is that you've used `dd` instead of `d` for a string like `"1-Jul-2013"`.

So use

```
DateTime date;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(hf_test.Value,
                            "d-MMM-yyyy",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format specifier, your date string is using a single-digit day but you are using the [leading 0 format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ddSpecifier) (`dd`). This expects your date string to have the day formatted as `01-31`.

You need to use the [non-leading 0 format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier) (`d`) which allows single digit days i.e.

```
 d-MMM-yyyy
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)